# Vanilla JavaScript with Function, function not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined-function

```
$(function() {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.id="filepicker";
 script.type="text/javascript";
 script.src="//api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js";
 var body=document.querySelectorAll("body")[0]; ;
 body.appendChild(script);
 var ButtonsArea = document.querySelectorAll('.frm-buttons')[0];
 var textArea = document.getElementById('text_editor_textarea');
 var button = document.createElement('span');
 var divText=document.createTextNode("Upload File");
 button.id="newDoc";
 button.setAttribute("onclick","getPick()");
 button.appendChild(divText);
 ButtonsArea.appendChild(button);

  function getPick(){
   filepicker.setKey('AWpNcAmH9TmiWtEgHsFwBz');
   filepicker.pick({
    mimetypes: ['text/*'],
    services:['COMPUTER'],
    maxSize:50*1024
   },function(FPFile) {
     var docFile = FPFile.url;
     textArea.value=textArea.value+'[url]'+FPFile.url+'+'+FPFile.filename+'[/url]';
     });
  }
});
```

my getPick() function is being said it is not defined is there something that I am missing from all of the JavaScript, maybe the JavaScript timing is off since everything is being created dynamically?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but setting the click event as an attribute with a string is not good practice. Try using `addEventListener` and pass the function as an object, that's the beauty of JS.

Comment: ok, see this is my first Vanilla code :D so what do I do? button.addEventListener('click',getPick()); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you declare a function within the scope of another function, it is limited to the scope of that function. When you call `getPick()` on the element's `onclick` attribute, it is executed in the global scope. `getPick` doesn't exist there.

You can instead simply assign the function as the `onclick` property:

```
button.onclick = getPick;
```

You can increase the flexibility of your code by using `addEventListener`, which would look like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', getPick, false);
```

This allows you to have more than one `click` handler on the button if you should so choose, but it isn't compatible with old versions of Internet Explorer. `button.onclick =` is compatible with almost all browsers going back a very long way into Internet history!

Note that in both those cases you are using `getPick` rather than `getPick()`. The former is a reference to the function; the latter executes the function and gives you its return value.

Comment: both work. thank you very much. can I ask why we don't have to do getPick() on either or?

Comment: As I say in my answer, `getPick` means "give me a reference to the function, so we can execute it later", while `getPick()` means "execute the function now and give me its return value".

Comment: oh my bad, completely skipped that part :D Thank you for the explanations.

Comment: @EasyBB: Read on "first class" functions. JavaScript is a functional language, functions are just objects that you can pass around. Once you understand that, read about "higher order" functions and you're in JavaScript paradise :)

Comment: lol. @elclanrs do you possibly have a document I read about this?

Comment: @EasyBB: Check these tutorials by John Resig (creator of jQuery). http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Answer (score 1):

The getPick() function is defined locally inside the anonymous on-ready function, so it's not visible to the onclick handler.

Try moving the getPick function outside the `$(function() { });` block.

Alternatively, use proper event handling, something like the following:

```
button.click(function() {
    filepicker.setKey('AWpNcAmH9TmiWtEgHsFwBz');
    filepicker.pick({
        mimetypes: ['text/*'],
        services:['COMPUTER'],
        maxSize:50*1024
    }, function(FPFile) {
        var docFile = FPFile.url;
        textArea.value=textArea.value+'[url]'+FPFile.url+'+'+FPFile.filename+'[/url]';
    });
});
```

Comment: Since the element is dynamic wouldn't it be .on('click') ?

Comment: It's being created dynamically, but only once... so setting a handler directly like this will work, since it's being set on the object after it's created.

Comment: oh ok thanks, only reason I won't accept this is because .click() is jQuery and I am actually learning Vanilla now, I was bad and learned jQuery first so